# Generar imagen con doble tamaño en función de botón (php + imagecopyresized)

Tags: php, html, botón, entrada

Llevo ya unos días tratando de resolver esta duda, pero soy incapaz a pesar de que parece ser más sencilla de lo que quizás pienso.

Lo que tengo en estos momentos, es un código para conseguir crear una imagen con un texto incluido en su interior a partir de un botón que hay en una página php, que hace llamada a otra página php (aaa.php). Eso funciona, sin complicaciones, que es el código que muestro a continuación.

Y aquí viene el punto en el que no sé seguir, lo que busco es que una vez esté el texto introducido en el , haya la posibilidad de crear o de guardar la imagen en dos diferentes formatos, un tamaño grande (por ejemplo 200px de ancho) y un tamaño pequeño (por ejemplo 50px de ancho), con dos botones diferentes para lograrlo.

```html
<form method="get" action="aaa.php">
<input type="text" name="textaaa" id="textaaa">
<select name="aaa">
<option value='230|70'>Ejemplo1</option>
<option value='50|50'>Ejemplo2</option>
</select>
<button>Generar</button>
</form>





<?php 
// Set the content-type
$imagen = imagecreatefrompng('generador/NL/NL0.png'); 

// Create the image
$black = imagecolorallocate($imagen, 0, 0, 0);  

// The text to draw
if(isset($_GET['textNL0'])){
$texto=$_GET['textNL0'];
}else{
$texto="";
}

$texto = wordwrap($texto, 2, "  ");

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'fuente/NLMAT.ttf';

// Add the text
imagettftext($imagen, 48, 0, 48, 70, $black, $font, $texto);

// Save image
if (isset ($_GET["NL0"] ) ){ 
$wh=explode("|", $_GET["NL0"] );
$w=$wh[0]; $h=$wh[1]; }

$ancho = $w;
$alto = $h;
$newwidth = $ancho;
$newheight = $alto;

imagecopyresized($nuevaimagen, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $ancho, $alto);

header("Content-type: image/png"); 
imagepng($nuevaimagen);
?>
```

Sabríais cómo conseguir crear los dos botones para crear en una nueva página/guardar la imagen en función de los dos botones?

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Muchas gracias

"Editado con el código más actualizado"

Comment: No se entendió bien tu problema, pero me pregunto ¿por qué no guardas una sola imagen y la presentas con el tamaño que quieras luego valiendote de `width, height` o mediante reglas de estilo CSS?

Comment: El objetivo sería que el usuario pudiese elegir crear la imagen entre dos tamaños posibles, pero ya preestablecidos. Así cuando la crease, podría guardarla directamente en su ordenador con el tamaño que ha elegido.

Comment: Lo que se entiende en el planteamiento de la pregunta es que quieres crear dos imágenes con dos tamaños distintos. Si se trata de crearla con uno u otro tamaño, lo mejor sería agregar un `select` para que el usuario elija un tamaño y al pulsar el botón Generar le mandas el dato del select y en base a eso le das el tamaño a la imagen.

Comment: He probado con este nuevo código con el select como me recomendabas, pero simplemente la imagen no se muestra.<select name="aaa"><option value='230'>Ejemplo1</option><option value='50'>Ejemplo2</option></select>   

if( isset( $_POST['aaa'] ) ){
    if( $_POST['aaa'] === "230" ) {
        $ancho=$_POST (230);
    } elseif( $_POST['aaa'] === "50" ) {
        $ancho=$_POST (50);
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
} 
$width = 200;
$newwidth = $width;
$newheight = $height;
imagecopyresized($nuevaimagen, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $ancho, $alto);

Comment: Es que te haces un lío recuperando el valor del `select`... tienes que recuperarlo así simplemente: `if( isset( $_POST['aaa'] ) ){$width=$_POST['aaa']; //...}` haciendo eso, ya tienes en la variable `$width` el valor, cualquiera que sea. No tienes más que usar la variable `$width` en tu código y listo. Incluso, puedes poner dos valores en el `value` de cada `select`, uno para el ancho y otro para el largo. Por ejemplo: `<select name="aaa"><option value='230|70'>Ejemplo1</option><option value='50|50'>Ejemplo2</option></select>` y luego recuperas cada dato con `explode`...

Comment: ... haciendo esto: `if (isset ($_POST["aaa"] ) ){ $wh=explode("|", $_POST["aaa"] ); $w=$wh[0]; $h=$wh[1]; }` En ese caso, según la opción seleccionada, vas a tener en la variable `$w` el valor del ancho (230 ó 50 según el caso), y en la variable `$h` el valor del alto (70 ó 50 según el caso). Luego, sólo tienes que usar ambas variables para establecer el tamaño de la imagen. `_POST` es un array que te trae los valores que hay en los elementos posteados, y esos valores hay que buscarlos usando la clave `name` del elemento, o sea, esto no tiene sentido ninguno: `$ancho=$_POST (230);`

Comment: Y a continuación del if (isset (...) debería escribir el imagecopyresized para que funcionase?                                  
$newwidth = $w;
$newheight = $h;

imagecopyresized($nuevaimagen, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

Comment: No se lo que hace tu `imagecopyresized`, la cuestión es que si escribes bien tu código según el ejemplo anterior, en las variables `$w` y `$h` tendrás los dos valores que necesitas... No entiendo que son esos otros valores que pasas a la función ...

Comment: He estado intentando ponerlo como me has recomendado, pero soy incapaz de hacerlo funcionar. Creo que tengo el fallo principal con `$w` y `$h`, porque no encuentro como implementarlo en el código. Cuando trato de hacer `$ancho = $w` me da error en todas las ocasiones independientemente de cómo lo haga

Comment: Puede que se trate de un problema ajeno al planteado originalmente. Creo que deberías verificar si las variables `$w` y `$h` están recibiendo los valores correctamente mediante `var_dump($w);` y `var_dump($h);` Si los valores se muestran correctamente, entonces el que no funcione dependerá de otro problema, el cual escapa al alcance de esta pregunta, dado que tendrá que ver seguramente con la función que recibe los parámetros.

Comment: Pues añado lo último que he adjuntado en el ejemplo, pero aún sin conseguir encontrar el posible fallo. if (isset ($_GET["aaa"] ) ){ 
    $wh=explode("|", $_GET["aaa"] );
    $w=$wh[0]; $h=$wh[1]; }
$ancho = $w; $alto = $h; $newwidth = $ancho; $newheight = $alto;

imagecopyresized($nuevaimagen, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $ancho, $alto);

Comment: A ver, primeramente, estas líneas no tienen ningún sentido ni utilidad en tu código: `$ancho = $w;
$alto = $h;
$newwidth = $ancho;
$newheight = $alto;` Como ya he dicho, deberías tener en las variables `$w`  y `$h` los valores de alto y ancho que necesitas. No sé si te das cuenta que ese código no hace más que cargar tu programa. Cuando tienes un valor en una variable no tienes por qué igualar otra variable a ella. Tampoco dices si has probado si las dos variables reciben bien los datos. Yo creo que si no funciona el error podría estar en `imagecopyresized`. ¿Se trata de una función de PHP?

Comment: El `var_dump($w)` no me funciona. Ya he probado también eliminando `$ancho =  $w; $alto = $h; $newwidth = $ancho; $newheight = $alto;`, pero igualmente no sale nada. He probado modificando los componentes del `imagecopyresized`, pero al borrar `$newwidth` y `$newheight` quedan dos huecos libres de la formula originaria de `imagecopyresized`. Y sí, se trata de una función php, ambas páginas lo son. Se me ocurre que quizás tenga toda la página aaa.php mal ordenada, pero no se si eso es lo que ocurre en este caso.

Comment: Esto está mal: `$wh=explode("|", $_GET["NL0"] );` según tu HTML el  `select`  se llama `aaa`...  `<select name="aaa">`, entonces esa línea tiene que ir así: `$wh=explode("|", $_GET["aaa"] );`

Comment: Ya lo acabo de arreglar también, pero nada. La url en la que me debería salir la imagen me queda ahora mismo así: `aaa.php?aaa=www&aaa=230%7C70`, siendo www el texto que me debería salir en la imagen teniendo elegido en el select la opción de  `230|70 `.

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/163981/edit), poniendo el código de la función `imagecopyresized`. Tú debes crear un elemento HTML `img` al cual le debes poner un `src` correcto, y otorgarle etiquetas `witdh` y `height`, si es que quieres mostrar la imagen en la página.

Comment: Por ahora lo que me estaba saliendo era una página en php, y si quería guardar la imagen tenía que guardar con el botón derecho. Pero voy a intentar cambiarlo para que genere imagen. Ya he actualizado la pregunta.